# Elevation statistics for a given Area

Tags: arcobjects, elevation

I am attempting to determine the best way to calculate the Minimum and Maximum elevation for a defined area.

The area is defined by an `IPolygon`

The elevation is defined as an `ISurface`

### **Possible Solutions:**

1. The only way I can think of is to check every cell of the surface.  Is there a method that performs this?
2. In the comments, @whuber, suggested a Zonal Maximum.  Expanding on this idea, I've begun looking into the `IZonalOp`.

*Are there other options?*

Comment: You mean as in a [zonal maximum](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000wt000000.htm)?

Comment: @whuber, that sounds like it might be it.  Thanks for the search term I needed.

Comment: There may be other options depending on the format of the data.  Search our site for [grid +statistics](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=grid+%2Bstatistics).

Comment: Chris, I have the same exact issue. Did you manage to find a proper solution?

Comment: @Konrad I'm pretty sure I ended up manually checking every cell in the polygon to build my statistics. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code to verify or share any more insight :-/

Comment: Thanks for information. I managed to perform this operation without checking every single cell as it takes a long time to complete. Here is my answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173093/how-to-find-a-point-with-highest-elevation-in-area-using-arcobjects/173850#173850